# PhoneGap alert system not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So I'm building a much bigger app but I'm having trouble getting this simple code to work which will end up being essential to our project and I cant figure out why. I am very new to Phonegap so any help is great. Here is my code:
https://github.com/dezert99/RIME/blob/master/www/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js file :https://github.com/dezert99/RIME/blob/master/www/index.js
Normal alerts, nor the alerts with the notifications plugin are showing up.

Comment: i just import your project and alerts are working fine .

Comment: yes its working for me ...

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in your code:

- All of your code has to run AFTER the deviceready event is fired.
- Don't mix inline and external code.

That means:

Delete your javascript code in your HTML document, except this lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
</script>
```

app.initialize() is starting your application logic, which is sitting in index.js

Modify your index.js like this (code not tested!):

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        alert("purple lizards");
        navigator.notification.alert("Hi", alertDismissed, 'test', 'yay');
        function alertDismissed(){
            // Do something when alert has error
        }
        app.showGeoLocation();
    }, showGeolocation: function () {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostion(onSuccess, onError);

        function onSuccess(position) {
            navigator.notification.alert(
                'Lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' + 'Lon: ' + position.coords.longitude,  // message
                alertDismissed,         // callback
                'Location',            // title
                'YAY'// buttonName
            )
        }

        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Nope, this isn't working either :(. The code make sense and should absolutely work but phonegap just isn't having it today. The emulator is just telling me that the device is ready. Any clue? (new code is in the github)

Comment: What is the console telling about errors? Are you using phonegap or cordova and are the plugins installed correct?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help but I have moved on to a different platform